# Bembo package 'fbb' with option 'altP' stops ligatures working

Tags: ligatures

When the option altP is used for the fbb package the ligatures don't appear anymore. This code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[altP]{fbb}
\begin{document}
P f ff fi ffi fj
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

which has the desired open 'P' but none of the ligatures, (cf.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fbb}
\begin{document}
P f ff fi ffi fj
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

). My question is twofold: what in the implementation of the option 'altP' causes this, and how can one acheive the same open 'P' without affecting the ligatures?

Comment: Version 1.13 of `fbb` solves the issue! `:-D`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `altP` option, the chosen font is `fbbP-Regular-tlf-t1`. Producing a table for it shows the expected ligatures

[image]

However, if I try `tftopl fbbP-Regular-tlf-t1`, I see no rule for the `ff` ligature. There is

```
(LABEL O 33)
(LIG C l O 37)
(LIG C i O 36)
```

which should produce the `ffi` and `ffl` ligatures, on the condition that `ff` is mapped to `O 33` (octal 33), which it isn't. Indeed, the program for `f` has

```
(LABEL C f)
(LIG C j O 30)
(LIG C i O 34)
(LIG C l O 35)
```

and you see that

```
(LIG C f O 33)
```

is unfortunately missing. It's impossible to fix it on the TeX side.

The same happens for the bold font. The italic fonts (medium and bold) have no P variant, so they're good.

## Update

Version 1.13 of `fbb`, released on 2017-06-24, solves the issue:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[altP]{fbb}

\begin{document}

P f ff fi ffi fj

{\itshape P f ff fi ffi fj}

{\bfseries P f ff fi ffi fj}

{\bfseries\itshape P f ff fi ffi fj}

\end{document}
```

will produce

[image]

Thanks to Michael Sharpe for the quick fix.

Comment: Thanks for that @egreg- do you know if it is possible to replicate the behaviour of the 'altP' option on the TEX side manually?

Comment: I mailed the package maintainer about the issue.

Comment: @GWM No, it is not possible. I think that Michael Sharpe will take care of the problem very soon, as usual of him. By the way, we should give him big thanks for his great work with fonts.

Comment: Indeed, his package comes out beatifully overall.